# What's the concert pitch for Saint Petersburg Philharmonic?

Tags: tuning

Is it 440 Hz? Or 442? Does anyone know? It sounds like 440 but I want to make sure.

Comment: Do you have a recording? You could try to measure it with your tuner or with a reference sound.

Comment: @harper Yes, but there's no guarantee the recording itself wasn't pitch-shifted during processing.     Back to the question: who says they always tune to the same pitch in the first place? They probably do, but...

Comment: Why dod care if you have nothing to compare?

Comment: Google the orchestra, find an email address for a staff member or musician in the orchestra, write to them, and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Likely 443.  That's what half a dozen other Russian orchestras use, claims http://members.aon.at/fnistl/page3.html (found via [Why are orchestras tuned differently?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/776/why-are-orchestras-tuned-differently) ).